# Can't make safe execution

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

After logging in to my db, I try to execute safe SQL-Commands.
I have a method which prepares SQL-Queries for me. The string itself and a list called `data`.

This is how I intent to do it

```
s = SELECT %s FROM %s
    WHERE %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%' OR 
    %s LIKE '%%%s%%';

#list converted to tuple
data = ('*', 'studierende', 'vorname', u'jo', 'nachname', u'jo', 'adresse1', u'jo', 'adresse2', u'jo', 'stadt', u'jo', 'land', u'jo', 'email', u'jo', 'tel', u'jo')

cursor.execute(s, tuple(data))
```

The error I get is

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'studierende'" LINE 1: SELECT '*' FROM 'studierende'
```

Comment: Your asterisk and the table name (`'studierende'`) should not be in quotes. And don't you get an error for how you defined variable `s`?

Answer (score 0):

To pass identifiers use `AsIs` from the [extensions module](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs). The other parameters need [adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#python-types-adaptation)

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

query = """
    select %s
    from %s
    where %s like '%%' || %s || '%%'
;"""

data = (AsIs('*'), AsIs('studierende'), 'vorname', u'jo')
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

It is necessary to join the `%` character to the parameter value.

Comment: Why should I use `AsIs` only for the first two items?

Comment: @Saphire Because the other parameters need adaptation. Check the updated link.

Comment: How should I do the AsIs, when all data is on a long list?
Should I append new items with `AsIs` to the list or should I use `AsIs` only when passing to `.execute`?